# Laravel File Copy: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, file, copy

I am using `File::copy` to copy the uploaded file from the main folder into my target folder. But it keeps saying there is no such file or directory.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{        
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'product_id' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'file' => 'required',
        'file.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,svg,gif,csv,xlsx,pdf,docx',
        'publish' => 'required',
    ]);

    $fileData = [];
    
    if($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('file') as $file)
        {
            $path = public_path('storage/documents/'.$request->product_id);
            $fileName = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($path, $fileName);

            $target = public_path('storage/documents/download');
            \File::copy($path.$fileName, $target.$fileName); // errors here

            $fileData[] = $fileName;
        }
        $data['file'] = json_encode($fileData);
    }

    $document = Document::create($data);

    return redirect()->route('product.index')->with('success','Document added successfully');
}
```

How can I solve this problem or is there any other way to upload same file on 2 folders?

Answer (score 0):

You may need a directory separator between your paths and the file name like this:

```
\File::copy($path.$fileName, $target.$fileName); // errors here
\File::copy($path.'/'.$fileName, $target.'/'.$fileName); // errors corrected
```

Comment: Then try dumping your paths to see if they are the expected directories.

Comment: dd($path): `"C:\wamp64\www\myprojectname\public\storage/documents/3"`

Comment: the path is correct, the difference is only the backslash and forward slash

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug your code. Follow these steps either

1. Try to print the value of file path. If you found anything wrong, change it.
2. Open `session.php` file in config folder and look for `storage_path`
3. Change your folder permission, but it saying no directory so may be issue is something else.
4. Clear you config or other cache by using `php artisan cache:clear` or `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: the `storage_path` in my config is `'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),`

Comment: Then try to clear cache and print the value of storage path to check whether it is correct

Comment: I stored both files inside the public path, and the paths die dump are correct.

Comment: dd($path): `C:\wamp64\www\myprojectname\public\storage/documents/3`

Comment: Looks like slashes are wrong.
Change them and try with new one.

Answer (score 0):

$file->move($path, $fileName);

You are moving the file , check its moved there or not first.

$target = public_path('storage/documents/download');
\File::copy($path.$fileName, $target.$fileName); // errors here

Your errors seems to related with file that you moved is moved properly in that directory or not. it should solve if naming is correct

```
\File::copy(base_path('test.text'),base_path('public/test.text'));
```

Check name and move file.